# Compare two files line by line and move matches to a third one

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have two files file-1.txt and file-2.txt:

**file-1.txt**:

```
vim-id|name|salary|job
100|AAA|4000|MD
101|BBB|3500|Designer
102|CCC|3250|Designer
103|DDD|4500|MD
```

**file-2.txt**:

```
vim-id|product|version
101|BOB|2.0
101|CAT|2.1
101|CAT|2.5
102|MICRO|5.1
102|SOFT|7.5
```

I need to compare column values (e.g. vim-id) and if there is a match of `vim-id` in both files, move the relevant rows to a different file: **file-3.txt**. Where we should first add the content of **file-1.txt** and then of **file-2.txt**.

Example output:

**file-3.txt**:

```
101|BBB|3500|Designer
101|BOB|2.0
101|CAT|2.1
101|CAT|2.5
102|CCC|3250|Designer
102|MICRO|5.1
102|SOFT|7.5
```

Note: This is an example. I have a huge volume of files to process.

Could you help me, please? Comparing  is slow that's why I am asking you.

Below is my code:

```
while read line
do
        for i in `echo $line | cut -d '|' -f'1'`
        do
       if grep -q "$i" file-2.txt  ; then
                echo $line >> file-3.txt
                grep -i "$i" file-2.txt  >> file-3.txt
        fi
        break
        done
done < file-1.txt
```

Comment: Well, what have you tried so afr? Or are you expecting us to write the code for you?

Comment: i edited just now. regarding to question, i have huge volume of files. for comparing, job time takes around 7 hours. that's why i am asking you to reduce process time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with this `awk`:

```
$ awk -v FS="|" 'FNR==1 {next} FNR==NR {a[$1]=$0; next} ($1 in a) {if (!b[$1]) print a[$1]; print; b[$1]++}' f1 f2
101|BBB|3500|Designer
101|BOB|2.0
101|CAT|2.1
101|CAT|2.5
102|CCC|3250|Designer
102|MICRO|5.1
102|SOFT|7.5
```

#### Explanation

- `-v FS="|"` set the field separator to `|`.
- `FNR==1 {next}` skip the headers of both files.
- `FNR==NR {a[$1]=$0; next}` read the first file, storing the lines with the 1st field as index.
- `($1 in a) {if (!b[$1]) print a[$1]; print; b[$1]++}` when reading the 2nd file, check if the 1st field is in the stored array `a[]`, print:

  - if the value did not appear yet, print the corresponding line from 1st file.
  - print the current line in 2nd file.